# Window titlebar text cropped

Tags: gnome, 19.10, titlebar

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10  (from 18.04 LTS), I noticed that when I switch to a Firefox window from another application, the Firefox title bar doesn't show the full text, but a cropped and unaligned version (see below):

[image: title bar cropped and unaligned]

Here is the expected appearance of the title bar:

[image: correct appearance of title bar]

The issue corrects itself as soon as I switch tabs in Firefox, but I wonder where this minor inconvenience comes from?

I am using Gnome with Unite and Ubuntu Dock (along with some other extensions) and the issue is replicated in different user themes.

EDIT: I realized this is not specifically a Firefox issue. It happens with other software too, but I noticed it first with the browser.

EDIT 2: The issue only arises when the window is maximised and the title appears in the top bar. This is handled by the Unite extension.

Comment: Are you using pixel-saver extension or an extension that removes titlebar from maximized windows?

Comment: @Joaquin: Yes, that is also handled by the Unite extension

Comment: You should refer to them on this matter as they control the CSS changes to gnome-shell . My initial reaction is that they have a limit to the title lenght that somehow gets removed when you focus on the window.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by  Joaquín Ayuso de Paúl, the problem was in the Unite extension and was resolved by using the newest version of the extension.